# use data from server in angular

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, service, controller

I am trying to use data I get from the server in my angular code.

To do this, I first receive the data in my HTML file with the following code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var __firstName= <%- JSON.stringify(givenName) %>;
  </script>
```

Then, I inject it in a service in my .js file:

```
myApp.service('user', function() {
  return givenName=function(){
    var user = __firstName;
    return user;
  };  
});
```

which I inject in my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('frontApp', []);

    myApp.controller('teammateInviteCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', '$http', '$window', '$log', '$timeout', 'user', function ($scope, $element, $http, $window, $log, $timeout, user) {

      $scope.account = {
        given_name: user.givenName(),
        family_name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        company: '',
        phone: ''
      };

    //some code

    }]);
```

But here I get an empty result for `$scope.account.given_name`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you used `console.log` to see where the data is being lost?

Comment: the data is defined properly on the HTML file but I lose it in the js file

Comment: which js file? Do you see the data in the service before it is used in the controller?

Comment: You probably need to inject __firstName into your service. I bet that is where the data is being lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend ng-init. 
Example.

```
 <div ng-init="user=<%- JSON.stringify(givenName) %>">
```

**Note: I would strongly suggest to user a rest API and get the data as a JSON get from the server instead of this circus. But if you are hell bent on doing it this way, ng-init is much better solution compared to what you are trying to achieve.**